# How to edit the whole form by clicking on the list item in react?

Tags: reactjs, list, react-forms

Hello I am new to react . I am working on an react assignment , where I can add student details using form  . In another page I am displaying the list of the students with just student name displaying in each list element . Now on clicking the particular list element I should be able to collect its index and also should be able to redirect to edit page of that particular student form using

Comment: can you post the data that you receive for rendering students list ? and does it include any api to fetch a particular user details to edit in form?